# Is there any way to iterate and take out 3d slices of a tensor?

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, keras, tensor

Is there a way to iterate over values of a 3D tensor for multiplication?
I have a 3x3 mask that I want to multiply with each 3 dimensional pixels of an rgb image

AN equivalent implementation is, say I have a 3x3 tensor which is a mask and a nonex200x200x3 rgb image. I want to multiply the 3x3 mask with the (r,g,b) value at (0,0,:) and then again with (0,1,:) and so on until (0,199,:) and then on to (1,0,:) all the way upto (199,199,:) to produce a (200,200,3) array.
This is because each of 3x3 mask by 3x1 element is supposed to yield a 3x1 element (or a 3D pixel) for each of 200x200 pixels in the input image.

slicing is easy enough in a numpy array since I can iterate using indices, but is there any way to do so in Keras?
Any help is highly appreciated
Thanks

Keras.backend.dot is able to carry out the actual multiplication, but how to go about actually taking the slice?

Comment: Okay, I thought of a roundabout way. Since the mask is a constant, theoretically, I would not need to update weights. So, as long as I can convert the tensor into a numpy array, it is possible to iterate. The problem now is that keras.backend.eval() is giving out errors saying that the input should be defined- which it IS, via a placeholder (it is working if I remove this section). Any help?